# OpenGeo SDK modify the getfeatureinfo popup

Tags: boundless-suite, sdk

I would like to modify the opengeo sdk gxp.FeatureEditPopup.
I want to construct a clickable hyperlink, I would like to add a new field to the popup that would be "http://someurl.com/" followed by a field from my data: "http://someurl.com/someDataField".
Any ideas would be appreciated.
Ben

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `editorPluginConfig` config option to configure a custom editor plugin. Look at https://github.com/opengeo/gxp/blob/master/src/script/plugins/FeatureEditorGrid.js to see the default plugin. Then, with help from the Ext JS documentation, configure custom field renderers. And note that what you want to achieve will only work in read-only mode.

Comment: Thank for the feedback, this sounds like a big commitment for a simple feature. Perhaps I will add a view in Geoserver that will include the hyperlink. If I do this, is there a way to make a hyperlink clickable inside the getFeatureInfo popup?

Comment: If you use text/html as feature info format, and create the template on the server, you're all way there already.

Answer (score 1):

first for all, you should a string field in your vector table that contains the url like this http://www.htmlpoint.com' TARGET='_new'>Visita HTMLpoint
after that, you must define the info format = test/html in the geoexplorer map composer.