# How to FeatureEditorGrid configure and use in FeatureEditor

Tags: openlayers-2, boundless-suite, geoext

I am new user of OpenGeo suite. I want to configure FeatureEditorGrid plugin to change the column header to display name. My basic requirement is to customize column label like my table column is "pop" and want to display "Population" in FeatureEditor popup.

I have refer this question [modify the GetFeatureInfo popup](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63721/opengeo-sdk-modify-the-getfeatureinfo-popup/63769#63769). So is it possible to modify FeatureEditor popup. I have tried like this:-

Include plugin :-

```
 * @require plugins/FeatureEditor.js
 * @require plugins/FeatureEditorGrid.js
```

And add reference in Tools section :-

```
{
    ptype: "gxp_editorgrid"
    ,propertyNames: {"project_id_fk": "Project ID",  "output_code": "Output Code"}
}
```

But it gives error, I don't know what I am missing.

```
Error: Could not create tool plugin with ptype: gxp_editorgrid
attributes = feature.attributes;
```

Is it possible to modify Featureedit popup??

Any suggestion will always welcome.

Answer (score 1):

For a featuregrid plugin, you can set the propertyNames in outputConfig:

```
{
    ptype: 'gxp_featuregrid',
    featureManager: 'featuremanager',
    outputConfig: {
        id: 'featuregrid',
        title: 'Features',
        propertyNames: {
            // key: value
        }
    },
    outputTarget: 'east'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I dont found how to configure it so I have **customize FeatureEditorGrid.js**. and **added custom code** like (I know this is not a right approach but i dont found useful docs.. :( )

```
    this.customEditors[name] = new Ext.grid.GridEditor({
                        field: Ext.create(fieldCfg),
                        listeners: listeners
                    });
//custom code....
     this.propertyNames= {"project_id_fk": "Project ID",
                      "output_code": "Output Code"}
```

If anyone help me in configuring code then i will update my code... I hope someone will help me.